# openvpn private dns resolution

Tags: dns, openvpn, amazon-web-services

I am deploying openvpn for an AWS vpc, and I in order to have private DNS (route 53) resolution, I had to add the following to the server.conf file:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.2”
```

However now, all the traffic is going through the vpn, whereas I would like to only have the private dns and vpc ips to go through.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push "redirect-gateway def1"` is making your client send all traffic thru VPN tunnel. However, what you are trying to accomplish is called split-tunneling.

What you need to do is to delete `push "redirect-gateway def1"` and change the routing table to route only private IP addresses (RFC 1918) thru the VPN.

This can be accomplished by following these steps:

1. delete `push "redirect-gateway def1"` from your configuration,
2. Add the following routes to your config:

   > push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 vpn_gateway"
   >
   > push "route 172.16.0.0 255.240.0.0 vpn_gateway"
   >
   > push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 vpn_gateway"

Comment: Hi @Algeriassic, could you explain me what these 3 lines mean? Because I am facing this problem [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1252230/openvpn-dns-split-tunnelling-issue-when-multiple-simultaneous-vpn-connections) and I think the issue may be linked to these lines.

Comment: Hi @ptou, these 3 lines are adding entries to the routing table to make only traffic destined to 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16 go through the VPN and all other traffic go out of the tunnel (directly to Internet)